# already installed the cpu version Pytorch,but now I want to change it to Gpu version ,how could I do?

Tags: python, pytorch

1.wonder need uninstall the cpu version pytorch first?
2.I tried follow sm tutorials ,install the cuda 11.4 and cudnn,then follow Pytorch website :conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch

but got :

```
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.


# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 261, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
        self.load()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 209, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 371, in _load
        raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 694, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
        resp = conn.urlopen(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
        self._prepare_proxy(conn)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
        conn.connect()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
        conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
        return ssl_wrap_socket(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
        ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
        return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
        return self.sslsocket_class._create(
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
        raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
    ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

`$ C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install --yes --prefix C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3 pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
                     PATH=C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Libr
                          ary\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\
                          Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\anaco
                          nda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\Administrat
                          or\anaconda3;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:
                          \Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\
                          anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Wind
                          ows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\W
                          indowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\
                          bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;E:\newfolder\ffmpeg-20200
                          716-d11cc74-win64-static\bin\;E:\20-6-20修电脑后重装软件\20200903文间整理(ai)\2020
                          ML重要！\jupyter深度学习（重要！）\我的项目;E:\20-6-20修电脑后重装软件\20200903文间整理(ai)\2020ML
                          重要！\jupyter深度学习（重要！);C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3;C:\Users\Adminis
                          trator\anaconda3\python.exe;C:\Users\wwq;;%SystemRoot%\system32;%Syste
                          mRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerSh
                          ell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Administrator\anacon
                          da3;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Ad
                          ministrator\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3
                          \Library\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Adminis
                          trator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\wwq;
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3
       user config file : C:\Users\Administrator\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Administrator\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.1
    conda-build version : 3.21.4
         python version : 3.8.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.4=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


    An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
    
    Upload did not complete.
```

---

also use pip didn't work.

so,I noticed that the pytorch website use 11.3 cuda,but I installde 11.4 cuda,does this matter?
I got stucked ,need some help,thanks.

Comment: Can you provide OS info?

Comment: what is OS info?I got this error info from jupyter notebook

Comment: mean from win command line? or anaconda prompt?

Comment: I mean what Operating System (=OS) you are using, and which version, which editor, ... some more info that could help experts to better assess your problem

Comment: oh,sure,windows 10 64,thanks